# Arcane Disciple and Spell Versatility - Casting high level Domain spells with your main casting attribute?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spellcasting, attributes

Can you use Spell Versatility from Geomancer, to "mix and match your spellcasting parameters" to change the Arcane Disciple's Wisdom requirement to your primary arcane spellcasting attribute (eg Int for Wizards or Char for Sorcerers)?

> Arcane Disciple (Feat, Complete Divine)
>
> You may learn these spells as normal for your class; however, you use Wisdom (rather than the normal ability for your spellcasting) when determining the save DC for the spell. In addition, **you must have a Wisdom score equal to 10 + the spell’s level in order to prepare or cast a spell gained from this feat.**

combined with

> Spell Versatility (Class feature of Geomancer, Complete Divine)
>
> **[H]e can mix or match spellcasting parameters from any of his classes** to gain the maximum possible advantage for any spell with a spell level equal to or less than his spell versatility score. Thus, as a 4th-level geomancer, he can cast any of his 3rd-level or lower sorcerer/wizard spells with no chance of arcane spell failure from armour. (The druidic prohibition against metal armour still applies to druid/geomancers, however, since this stricture stems from a spiritual oath rather than a practical limitation.) The geomancer may use his Wisdom modifier to set the save DC for arcane spells, or his Charisma or Intelligence modifier (whichever he would normally use for arcane spells) to set the save DC for divine spells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Ask your DM.

This is just an unclear situation. You can mix and match parameters from any of your spellcasting *classes*, but if you’re a wizard with Arcane Disciple, any spells from that domain that you cast as a wizard are *already* using the “parameters” of your wizard class, with respect to Arcane Disciple spells. For Arcane Disciple spells, your “wizard parameters” involve Wisdom. It’s not clear if you would count as having any class that uses Intelligence, with respect to these spells.

(If you also have levels in another Intelligence-using class, though, you’d be golden.)

This is super-nit-picky, and even at the most technical, it’s far from a certain argument. So ultimately, ask your DM. The rules, as written, aren’t clear. I have a hard time imagining any DM not allowing you to, but since I am not your DM, I cannot actually make that ruling for your game.

Answer (score 2):

### No

Just before the excerpt quoted in the question, the description of **Spell Versatility** states:

> He still acquires and prepares his spells in the normal manner for his individual spellcasting classes. When he casts them, however, he can mix or match...

So, while a sufficiently-high-leveled Geomancer may be able to use Intelligence to *cast* a spell acquired via **Arcane Disciple** ([this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/165793) discusses why this may not be the case), it is still necessary to use Wisdom to *prepare* such a spell in the first place. Spontaneous casters may be able to get around this, but that's finicky enough that I'd certainly recommend discussing it with your DM first.

Comment: I'm looking at this in context of the Sha'ir, so that loophole might be sufficient. I didn't want to introduce this fact as it gives an additional level of complexity as the Sha'ir needs not know a spell to cast it, and he doesn't prepare them but fetches them.